# How json dumps None to empty string

Tags: python, json

I want Python's `None` to be encoded in json as empty string how? Below is the default behavior of `json.dumps`.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
'["foo", {"bar": ["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]'
```

Should I overwrite the json encoder method or is there any other way?

Input data is not that simple as in above example, on every request it could be changed to different data structure. Its difficult to write a function for changing data structure.

Comment: If you want the real answer then you're going to need to provide a better justification...

Comment: My input data is not that simple as in above example, so I am looking to change the `None` to empty string through `json.dumps`.

Comment: It should be noted that `None` is not the same thing as an empty string; so keep that in mind when converting. The correct equivalent of `None` is `null`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes you are right but I have to send this json data to mobile side and there Iphone and Android guys having problem with `null`, therefore I am converting this to empty strings.

Comment: The thing to be careful of is if in your code the difference between `None` and `''` is significant, and you're expecting data back; you  have some potential ambiguity between whether a returned `''` is indeed a `''` or is meant to be converted back to `None` again...

Comment: Regardless of how "complicated" your data structure is, it shouldn't be too hard to write a little function that walks through it to replace all the `None`s with `''`. Whether that's a good idea is highly questionable.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim see my update in question

Comment: I presume it's just lists and dictionaries since those are what are finally serialised into json. If that's the case, it doesn't matter even if it is "changing". You can still replace all dictionary values and all list elements which are `None` with `''` using a generic walker function.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim can you please update your answer with that function?

Comment: I've added a piece of a function. Try to extend it to handle all your cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the object you're encoding, use an empty string instead of a `None`.

Here's an untested function that walks through a series of nested dictionaries to change all `None` values to `''`. Adding support for lists and tuples is left as an exercise to the reader. :)

```
import copy

def scrub(x):
    ret = copy.deepcopy(x)
    # Handle dictionaries. Scrub all values
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        for k,v in ret.items():
            ret[k] = scrub(v)
    # Handle None
    if x == None:
        ret = ''
    # Finished scrubbing
    return ret
```

Answer (score 4):

It would be better to process the data you want to encode and replace `None`s with empty strings. After all, that is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly improved version that handles lists and tuples as well:

```
def scrub(x):
    # Converts None to empty string
    ret = copy.deepcopy(x)
    # Handle dictionaries, lits & tuples. Scrub all values
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        for k, v in ret.items():
            ret[k] = scrub(v)
    if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
        for k, v in enumerate(ret):
            ret[k] = scrub(v)
    # Handle None
    if x is None:
        ret = ''
    # Finished scrubbing
    return ret
```

I used it when using `jsonschmea` module. It seems that it cannot handle `None` type, and throws: `jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError:  None is not of type u'string'`. So this takes care of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use the [json.JSONEncoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder), if you have an object with lists, tuples, dicts, strings and None, you can use the class shown afterwards to replace None to empty string.

`default` is the method originally used to convert non json types to python, this time we use it to convert the None to empty string.

`encode` is used to encode the json, that's why we use it with the new default to use the new method

```py
class NoneToEmptyJSON(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if o == None:
            o = ''
        elif type(o) == dict:
            return {self.default(key): self.default(value) for key, value in o.items()}
        elif type(o) == list or type(o) == tuple:
            return [self.default(item) for item in o]
        return o
    def encode(self, o):
        return super().encode(self.default(o))
```

Then instead of dump, you use encode with the class

```py
NoneToEmptyJSON().encode(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
```

Then the result is:

```py
'["foo", {"bar": ["baz", "", 1.0, 2]}]'
```

You can also use params if you want indent or other things this way:

```py
NoneToEmptyJSON(ensure_ascii=False, indent=2).encode(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
```